# How to get values of a dynamically populated list added through jquery in servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am facing an issue. I have a jsp where user selects 2 dates from calendar. Now after selection I have to dynamically populate 2 ordered lists, one with all the months between those 2 dates and one having number of working days in those months. I have achieved this by calling a JavaScript function on selection of dates which adds elements to those lists.
But I am facing issue that I am not able to get the values of those lists from request object. It always returns `null` value.

Here is the code inside scripts:

```
var monthlist = document.getElementById('monthList');
var valuelist = document.getElementById('valueList');


for(i=0; i<data.length/2; i++) {
    var monthName = document.createElement("li");
    monthName.innerHTML = data[i];

    var monthValue = document.createElement("li");
    monthValue.innerHTML = data[i+data.length/2];

    $("#monthList").append(monthName);
    $("#valueList").append(monthValue);

}
```

I have created two list in jsp like below:

```
<ol id="monthList"></ol>
<ol id="valueList"></ol>
```

The List getting populated properly on screen but when I try to fetch value of these list in servlet I am getting null

```
System.out.println("monthList="+httpServletRequest.getParameter("monthList"));
System.out.println("valueList="+httpServletRequest.getParameter("valueList"));
```

How can I get value of these lists in servlet

Answer (score 1):

Only the values of input elements like `<input>, <select>, <textarea>` and  are sent to the server side upon the submit of a parent .

The `<li>` is not an input element of any sort.